# Jol to find the offset of fields in the class

Tags: java, reflection, jol

I use jol to find the offset of the fields as below:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseClass(Field.class).toPrintable());
}
```

The output:

```
OFF  SZ   TYPE DESCRIPTION               VALUE
  0   8        (object header: mark)     N/A
  8   4        (object header: class)    N/A
 12   4        (object alignment gap)    
Instance size: 16 bytes
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 4 bytes external = 4 bytes total
```

The 3rd row shows (object alignment gap) but didn't show the offset of the fields such as override, name, type and such on.

How can I get those field's offset? Or is there other ways to get the offset?

Comment: What is the `Field` class here? `java.lang.reflect.Field`?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, u are right!

Comment: _other ways to get the offset?_ - Can you provide more details how you plan on using this data?. Maybe that'll help if there are other ways to do what you want

Comment: @OneCricketeer I hv no plan on using this data. Just curious of it.

Comment: Doesn't JOL work on an object instance? Not a class definition itself?

Comment: @OneCricketeer JOL can work on both object instance and class but sometimes it will only show (object alignment), no any field offset.

Comment: So, what are you expecting to see? Member has fields, but [Field does not](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html)

Comment: @OneCricketeer but when u clicked into the Field.class file, u would see a lot of fields there such as clazz, slot, name, type, modifiers, trustedFinal, isOverride...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JOL IntelliJ Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10953-jol-java-object-layout) shows the offset information, apparently.

Install the plugin, use `Field` somewhere in your code, put the cursor on the text `Field`, then go to Code -> Show Object Layout

[image]

Note that there is also a selector for the JVM implementation to use.

Interestingly, using `sudo` with the JOL command line tool report a different size for a `Field` object - 72 bytes for my JVM.

```
$ sudo java -jar jol-cli-latest.jar internals java.lang.reflect.Field
```

Output excerpt:

```
java.lang.reflect.Field object internals:
OFF  SZ   TYPE DESCRIPTION               VALUE
  0   8        (object header: mark)     0x0000000000000005 (biasable; age: 0)
  8   4        (object header: class)    0x0006e918
 12   4        (object alignment gap)    
Instance size: 72 bytes
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 4 bytes external = 4 bytes total
```

Comment: Wow, this is what I want. Thanks. I am going to accept answer but why use pure JOL can't show that?

Comment: @MichaelTsai I'm not sure why. Perhaps check the plugin's source code to see how they implemented.